# How to auto-login Firebase users at the start of an app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement a Home class which shows a Login screen for new users or auto-logins previously signed in users and brings them to directly to the app. However, when the code runs it shows login screens for signed in users.

From my understanding, the Future function is initially returning a null and the code finishes with "Login Page" being shown even though the Future later returns the current User.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    return _auth.currentUser();
}

Widget userLoggedIn() {
  getCurrentUser().then((user) {
    if (user != null) {
      //User is auto-logged in = build main app
      return new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Main App"),
        ),
      );
    } else if (user == null) {
      //New user = return null
      return null;
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return userLoggedIn() ??
      //New user = build login page
      new Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Login Page"),
        ),
      );
}

}
```

Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Why dont you create a simple login page and auto-login functionality to that page  and if there is a user logged in change the app route ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start the auto-login progress in your `LoginPage`'s `initState`,

`LoginPage` must be `StatefulWidget` to use `initState`

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      if (user != null) { //if there isn't any user currentUser function returns a null so we should check this case. 
        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
            // we are making YourHomePage widget the root if there is a user.
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourHomePage()),
            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

signOut with that method:

`FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()`

Comment: I implemented your code, but the navigator pushes to the new page even if the currentUser is signed out. I am using this method in a different part of the app to signout the user:
`Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async{
    await _auth.signOut().then((_) {
      print("User signed out");
    });
  }`

Comment: if there isn't any user `currentUser` function returns a `null` so we should check this case too. I forgot it , sorry about that. @OndřejRomancov edit my answer

Comment: I know this answer is old, but I have a question. Your code is working well, but when the user is logged in and he restarts the App it is showing the LoginScreen for a short amount of time. After this, the App moves to the HomeScreen. Is it possible to just move to the HomeScreen and Skip the LoginScreen? Your code is implemented in my LoginScreen's initState. Thanks!

Comment: @Tailor Yes is it possible, I think you should create a SplashPage or something else when waiting for currentUser, and make your controls in SplashPage, you have to draw something on the screen

Comment: @cipli onat Thanks, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *wait* until `_auth.currentUser()` returns the user.

Use `await` keyword and not `.then()`.

Change your `getCurrentUser()` method.

Return a `FirebaseUser` and not a `Future`.

`FirebaseUser currentUser = await authService.getCurrentUser();`

Comment: I can't seem to modify the getCurrentUser() method so that it returns a FirebaseUser instead of a Future